# ActionBar animation issues

Tags: java, android

I am using the ObservableScrollView library to show and hide the ActionBar as you are scrolling up and down an activity. This works well but when the ActionBar is animating sliding in or out a blank area at the bottom of the screen about the size of the ActionBar is briefly pushed up.

After searching similar issues the suggested solution is to the following line to onCreate():

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

This has had no visible effect and the issue is still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting my ActionBar to overlay content in the XML style.